# How to get unique data from two tables using mysql?

Tags: mysql

I have two tables one table has details of projects thats are unique and another table has image of this project but multiple.

I want one image with one project.

Structure of data :

```
Table 1:

Project_id  Project_Name 
291          Demo1
292          Demo2

Table 2:

Project_id   Img_name   Attr_id
291          p1.png     11
291          p2.png     12
```

I want to get image where attr_id is 11

So output will be

```
project_id    Project_name     Img_name    Attr_id
291           Demo1            p1.png       11
```

So How to do this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use mysql `JOIN`

```
select a.Project_id,a.Project_Name,b.Img_name,b.Attr_id   from table1 a join table2 b  ON a.project_id = b.project_id where b.attr_id=11
```

Answer (score 0):

In your case you can use the `JOIN`-function of mysql:

```
SELECT a.Project_id, a.Project_Name, b.Img_name, b.Attr_id
FROM table2 b INNER JOIN Table1 a ON ( b.Project_id = a.Project_id)
WHERE b.Attr_id = 11
```

Or you could just filter your Selection by a `WHERE ... AND`-Construction:

```
select * from table1 a,table2 b where a.project_id = b.project_id and attr_id=11
```

Both ways will result in the same output:

```
291  Demo1  p1.png  11
```

Comment: "Where ... AND" in this case is an implicit join. You should prefer the explicit join because it is faster to notice, so it is easier to read the query.

Answer (score 0):

you can have a `join`on these two tables for getting the result :

```
"select t1.project_id,t1.project_name,t2.img_name,t2.attr_id
from table1 t1,table2 t2
where t1.project_id=t2.project_id
and t2.attr_id=11";
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to specifically query the Attr_id try this one. Should get you the image with the lowest Attr_id related to the project

```
SELECT table1.project_id, table1.project_name, image.Img_name, image.Attr_id  
FROM table1 
    INNER JOIN (SELECT * FROM table2 ORDER BY Attr_id ASC LIMIT 1) 
        AS image ON table1.project_id = image.project_id 
WHERE table1.project_id = 291
```